# Why is the direction of stress shown along the direction of deformation?

Tags: forces, stress-strain

[image]

In the shown case of shear stress, which is a result of the deformation it undergoes, why is the direction of shear stress shown along the direction of deformation ?

Considering that an external force is the cause of the deformation and stress is the force that arises within the object and keeps it from disintegrating, shouldn't stress be in the direction opposite to the external force, and hence the direction of deformation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the shown case of shear stress, which is a result of the
>   deformation it undergoes

The deformation (shear strain) is the result of the shear stress. Not the other way around.

> Considering that an external force is the cause of the deformation and
>   stress is the force that arises within the object and keeps it from
>   disintegrating,

Shear stress us the cause of shear strain (deformation). Shear stress is the external force parallel to the surface divided by the area. What resists shear strain is the shear modulus property of the material.

> shouldn't stress be in the direction opposite to the external force,
>   and hence the direction of deformation ?

Stress is alway in the same direction as the force that causes it. Just like normal strain is due to normal stress and normal stress is the force normal to the surface area divided by the area, shear strain is due to shear stress and shear stress is the force parallel to the surface divided by the surface area.

For a given shear stress, the shear strain is proportional to the materials shear modulus. For a give normal stress, the normal strain is proportional to the materials modulus of elasticity (Young's modulus).

UPDATE:

In response to your follow up comments, the thing that opposes deformation (strain) due to externally applied stress are the intermolecular forces of attraction (that resist stretching) and repulsion (that resist compression). Think of those forces as springs between the molecules and the spring force as a restoring force. At the macroscopic level these forces are reflected in the materials shear modulus (for shear strain) and elastic modulus (for normal strain). The relevant equations in the linear elastic region for the material are

$$τ=Gγ$$
$$σ=εE$$

Where

$τ$ = shear stress, $G$ = shear modulus, and $γ$ = shear (transverse) strain.

And

$σ$ = normal stress, $E$ =  modulus of elasticity, and $ε$ = normal (axial) strain

The two moduli are related by

$$G=\frac{E}{2(1+ν)}$$

where $ν$ is poisson's ration (-(lateral strain)/(longitudinal strain).

> My findings: Sites such as Brittanica, Wikipedia, Brilliant, Vedantu,
>   Toppr, and my engineering curriculum, defines stress as internal force
>   and to be arising within the material, while sites such as physics,
>   phy.libre defines it as just amount of 'force applied'. I think that
>   it could be concluded that the widespread use of 'stress' is as
>   internal force while there are also cases of it being used as force
>   applied (like in the figure in question).

Actually, I think it is both. If you are looking only at the exterior of the object, the stress is an externally applied force divided by area. If you cut the body the free body diagram of each section will have both the external and internal stresses shown as balancing each other for equilibrium.

Refer to the diagrams below. The top diagrams shows axial (normal) compressive loading. The bottom diagrams show transverse (shear) loading. The diagrams to the right of each are free body diagrams of each half of the cut member. I've represented the intermolecular forces as springs. It is way over simplified for clarity, as the springs before loading are randomly oriented, and each atom should be shown interconnected by springs to all the neighboring atoms. The idea is to show that the internal forces/stress (shown in red) are due to the resistance of the intermolecular forces (represented by springs) to the external forces transmitted into the material by the externally applied load (shown in black).

The stiffness of the springs (spring constant) that resist deformation due to the external loading is reflected in modulus of elasticity and shear modulus in the equations previously given.

Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate by defining both stress and strain ? Until now I had thought that stress was an internal force (though magnitude is same as the external force). I now found (from Google) that both definitions exist. Is there a difference in definitions of stress or is it a misconception ? Why would graphs be stress-strain if the latter is dependent on the former and not the other way round ? Why would it be said that compressive load causes tensile stress ? [Most importantly; Are you sure about your answer ? (No offence)]

Comment: @Zam No offense taken. Stresses arise from external forces applied over area perpendicular to (normal stress) or parallel to (shear stress) the area. But you are correct that it creates interior forces at the microscopic level between neighboring particles. But the internal forces that prevent deformation are the attractive forces between the particles (I believe primarily electrostatic). Macroscopically those forces are reflected in the shear modulus and modulus of elasticity of a material.

Comment: @Zam I will be updating my answer to further elaborate.

Comment: @Zam See my UPDATE. Hope it helps.

Comment: My findings: Sites such as Brittanica, Wikipedia, Brilliant, Vedantu, Toppr, and my engineering curriculum, defines stress as internal force and to 
be arising within the material, while sites such as physics, phy.libre defines it as just amount of 'force applied'. I think that it could be concluded that the widespread use of 'stress' is as internal force while there are also cases of it being used as force applied (like in the figure in question).

Comment: @Zam Actually, I think it is both. If you are looking only at the exterior of the object, the stress is an externally applied force divided by area. If you cut the body the free body diagram of each section will have both the external and internal stresses shown as balancing each other for equilibrium. see my latest revision in an attempt to show this.

Comment: Hmm. That makes sense. Great. Please also clarify why external force is shown downwards in the figure showing shear stress.

Comment: @Zam That's  was only intended to show the color key, which I duplicated from the top diagram. As you can see in the actual diagram the external forces are shown horizontal. But I can see that it may cause confusion so I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a solid body at equibrium with some external forces acting on it and perform a virtual cut into 2 pieces. Stating that piece 1 is in equilibrium means that all external forces exerting on piece 1 are balanced with the resulting force from all internal efforts (stress) exerted by piece 2 on piece 1 on the boundary of the virtual cut. Now, you could choose to represent the internal efforts that piece 1 exerts on piece 2, and you would find that they are exactly the opposite, but this would not be so convenient to study the equilibrium of piece 1.

Comment: Does this actually answer the question ?

Comment: Well if you agree that the represented internal stresses are internal forces acting  just like any other forces on your system, the remaining of your question comes down to why Hooke's law holds?